# How do I parse emails sent to a gmail account and store their contents in my database?

Tags: node.js, email, express, gmail

I'm in an intro web dev class. I would like to be able to set up a web server that will routinely check email for a certain address (potentially a gmail account), parse the contents of the new emails, and store the contents in my DB. I'm using an ec2 instance running Ubuntu/express/node. I have found Mailin (http://mailin.io/doc) which does a lot of what I want, but the tutorial assumes too much background knowledge on email servers (smtp and the like) to be helpful to me. Existing tutorials that dumb it down would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I wanted by accessing the gmail API. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/

Answer (score 0):

If you have no experience with mail servers then it would make sense to use a service like Mailgun to process incoming mail. See:

- https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-receiving.html

You can easilu use Mailgun with Node:

- https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mailgun

Other services that can help you are Mandrill, Amazon Simple Email Service and many others.

Comment: This looks useful, but is basically the same as the link I provided. The tutorials start assuming you have some sort of mail server already set up on your server, which is what I am trying to do.